# How to allow Apache and MapServer access to data on different file system?

Tags: linux, apache, mapserver

I have a large hard drive I would like to store data  mapserver (Runs as a cgi-bin under Apache) but I am ruining in to errors when trying to access the data.

When I try and access any thing in the /bac/data/gis using mapserver I get:

msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'world'. msShapefileOpen(): Unable to access file. (/var/www/html/gis/world.shp) msShapefileOpen(): Unable to access file. (/bac/data/gis/global/world.shp)

from  the mapserver log file:

```
[Fri Aug  2 01:12:15 2013].100850 CGI Request 1 on process 28658
[Fri Aug  2 01:12:15 2013].105687 msDrawMap(): rendering using outputformat named png (AGG/PNG).
[Fri Aug  2 01:12:15 2013].105731 msDrawMap(): WMS/WFS set-up and query, 0.000s
[Fri Aug  2 01:12:15 2013].105819 msShapefileOpen(): Unable to access file. (/bac/data/gis/global/world.shp)
[Fri Aug  2 01:12:15 2013].105838 msShapefileOpen(): Unable to access file. (/var/www/html/gis/world.shp)
[Fri Aug  2 01:12:15 2013].105848 msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'world'.
[Fri Aug  2 01:12:15 2013].106077 mapserv request processing time (msLoadMap not incl.): 0.005s
[Fri Aug  2 01:12:15 2013].106085 msFreeMap(): freeing map at 0x1bdfde0.
```

I also tried accessing data directly using Apache to see if it could read anything in /bac/data/gis.  This was done by adding an ailes and directory directive to httpd.cfg file.
This to failed with the flowing error message in the httpd-error log.

[Thu Aug 01 22:52:37 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /gis/ denied (filesystem path '/bac') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

The file system is mounted as "/bac"  and the data is in /bac/data/gis
my httpd directorys are /var/www/[html cgi-bin]/

I have ensured +x permission on all directors in the /bac/dat/gis path. I all so disabled seliux as this is general the first thing I try when faceing an access denied situation.

Is it possible access data on other file system using Apache and cgi-bin scripts such as mapserver?

Comment: That certainly is possible. Servers like Apache and the like do not know anything about file system structure. If that file system has been mounted into the local file system then to the server it is a single file system. So most likely you have some other issue blocking that access, but it has nothing to do with the files located on another file system.

Comment: I have the same issue and seems I can't find the right permissions. Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As arkascha pointed out, the mount points and filesystems are irrelevant when considering access permissions. You should check that your apache user has access to those files:

```
user@host$ sudo su apache (apache may need to be replaced by httpd, www-data, check your apache config file to see under which user apache runs)
apache@host$ ls /bac/data/gis/global/world.shp
```

If the ls command returned a permission error, you have determined the cause of your error. In that case check that the permissions on /bac/data/gis/global/world.shp have "+r" for apache (that will probably be for the "others"), *and* that all the intermediate directories have +x.

```
sudo chmod o+r /bac/data/gis/global/world.*
sudo chmod o+x /bac
sudo chmod o+x /bac/data
sudo chmod o+x /bac/data/gis
sudo chmod o+x /bac/data/gis/global
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, something like `chgrp -R apache /var/www` can work, or I'm wrong ?